# Let $a_n>0$, increasing and $a_n\to\infty$ such that $\sum x_n/a_n$ converges. Then prove that $\frac{1}{a_n}\sum\limits_1^n x_n\to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n>0$, increasing and $a_n\to\infty$  and $\{x_n\}$ be a real sequence such that $\displaystyle{\sum \frac{x_n}{a_n}}$ converges. Then prove $\displaystyle{\frac{1}{a_n}\sum\limits_1^n x_n\to 0}$.

So there are $3$ information given-

1. $a_n>0$ and $a_n$ is increasing
2. $a_n\to\infty$
3. $\displaystyle{\sum\frac{x_n}{a_n}}$ converges

I got the following inequalities-

$\displaystyle{\frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}{a_n}\le \frac{a_1x_1/a_1+\cdots+a_n x_n/a_n}{a_n}\le \frac{a_nx_1/a_1+\cdots+a_n x_n/a_n}{a_n}=x_1/a_1+\cdots+ x_n/a_n}$

$\displaystyle{\frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}{a_n}\le \frac{a_1x_1/a_1+\cdots+a_n x_n/a_n}{a_1+\cdots+a_n}\le(x_1\ldots x_n)^{\frac{1}{a_1+\cdots+a_n}}}$

But none of them doesn't help to prove the limit to $0$. Can anyone help me in this regard? Thanks for help advance.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_lemma) can help.

Comment: In your second condition, do you actually mean $x_j$?

Comment: The second inequality is true if $x_i \ge 0$ for $i=1,2,\ldots $.